# How can I pass in numpy array to Flask API?

Tags: python, numpy, flask-restful

How can I use webargs or reqparse from `flask_restful` to pass a numpy array while making a POST call. I am able to pass arguments of other data types (string, int) with ease but numpy arrays get translated to unicode or throws an error.

I want to able to do something like:

```
from flask_restful import reqparse
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('url', type=str)
parser.add_argument('id', type=str, required=True)
# Pass in numpy array
parser.add_argument('arr', type=numpy.array, required=True)
```

I also tried with `webargs` but haven't found a way to make it compatible with numpy arrays. I have this set up:

```
from webargs import fields
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args
my_args = {'url': fields.Str(),
           'id': fields.Str(required=True),
           'arr': fields.Field()} # not sure what to put here
```

Is there a way to efficiently pass in a numpy array using a flask restful API?

Edit:
I've tried setting data type as List but get a new error indicating `u"'List' object is not callable"`.
I've changed:

```
# pass in numpy array
parser.add_argument('arr', type=fields.List(fields.Raw()))
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to figure this out? Currently experiencing this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756264/how-to-serialize-numpy-arrays#49809097

Answer (score -1):

The  [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/api.html#module-inputs) indicates some other data types than primitives. A numpy array can be interpreted as a list.

If you want to pass a numpy object to be able to use its methods, I think the parser will not work.